# How to calculate bit-security with Root Hermite factor?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I want to know relationship between bit security and Root Hermite factor.

How can I calculate bit security from Root Hermite factor.

(I want to know 1.00395, 1.00499, 1.00215, 1.00265 each)